# Sending a HTTP Request via Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

It is possible to trigger WordPress via WordPress API for a REST Request to a third party Website? If yes how?

BR
Timo

Comment: Can you be able to provide the more context about the issue?

Comment: I want to trigger via via the WordPress API a HTTP request to another Website and process some json information

Comment: Hello, As I understand: You want to get the result of external API from your WordPress installation, Is this correct?